# 1974 Honda Cb125 Not Starting + Strange Clicking Noise

Tags: honda, electrical, motorcycle, starting

I have a 1974 Honda Cb125.

The other day, she started fluttering at speeds above 30mph. I had run into this issue before, and it turned out to be a bad spark plug connection. I have since replaced the spark plug cable, and the plug itself. The bike ran fine after that.

I trucked my bike home, and started toying around with it. Not only is it now-impossible to start (before, it would start on the first kick), but with the key turned to on, a strange clicking sound is made (and my neutral indicator winks at the same rate as the clicking sound).

It is coming from the circle to the left of my battery (I can feel the vibration):

[image]

I do not know what that part is called, but I believe it is the blinker relay or condenser?

Answer (score 1):

It looks as though it is a relay. I cannot tell by the picture, but a relay is going to have three connections on it. One would be a ground, another is an energizer link (12v), and the third is going to be the power lead which provides power to wherever it's going to, which in this case is probably the ignition system.

Comment: what would be the source of the clicking? should I just replace the unit?

Comment: The relay is the source of the clicking. Replace it and you should be golden. I doubt it would even have to the exact same one, just one which matches the voltage of the bike (assuming 12v). You'd have to match the right connections, but any automotive relay should work just fine.

Comment: I am assuming there are (or should be) three wires on the one in the picture when I say this.

Comment: Make sure your battery is fully charged.